# Multicolumn or twocolumn text with reledmac

Tags: footnotes, two-column, multicol, reledmac

I am trying to figure out how to get the `reledmac` package to work with either the `multicol` package or the twocolumn book class. In my MWE I have two sets of footnotes defined: one is in the paragraph format and the other is a two column format. I need both sets of footnotes to span with the width of the whole page.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[papersize={6.5in,9.5in},margin=1in,bottom=1in, headheight=28pt, heightrounded, marginparwidth=1.75cm, marginparsep=3mm, columnsep=10pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\arrangementX[A]{paragraph}
\arrangementX[B]{twocol}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco\footnoteA{A\lipsum*[1]} laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore\footnoteB{B\lipsum*[2]} eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat\footnoteB{testing footnote here} cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\lipsum[3-4]


\end{document}
```

Here is a mockup of what I am looking to achieve: 
[image]

Comment: it seems it is a bug in reledmac. You could open an issue on reledmac issues manager.

Unfortunatly, I have no time yet for reledmac debugging.

Comment: as you don't use critical footnote, you coukd use other padckage that manage multiple level of footnotes